# Kotlin property with getter. Can I not specify an initial value?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I want to create a singleton class, but unfortunately, Android needs Context for almost anything so I need it to create an instance. So I just assumed the user called `init()`, and then return the instance. As you see below, if the `_instance` is null, an exception will be thrown, so the `get` method cannot return null.

But Kotlin says I must initialise `instance`. The things is, that MyClass cannot be created without a context. So I would like not to specify an initial value. How can I do that?

```
companion object
{
    protected var _instance:MyClass? = null;
    fun init(context:Context)
    {
        _instance = MyClass(context)
    }
    var instance:MyClass //<---This causes a compile error.
        get()
        {
            if(_instance==null) throw RuntimeException("Call init() first.");
            return _instance!!;
        }
}
```

Comment: lateinit var _instance:MyClass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `var` to `val` and it should work:

```
....
val instance: MyClass
....
```

A variable property (`var`) not only assumes a getter, but also a setter. Since you provided no setter, a default one was generated `set(value) { field = value }`. Despite is uselessness in this situation, the default setter uses `field`, thus requires its initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Use lateinit property

```
public class MyTest {
        lateinit var subject: TestSubject

        fun setup() {
            subject = TestSubject()
        }

        fun test() {
            subject.method()
        } 
}
```

Comment: I think `lazy` is a lot more appropriate than `lateinit` in this case as it will kind of automatically call the setup() method