# Should I initialise a singleton in onCreate by subclassing Application?

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton

I tried to use [a singleton like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163095/kotlin-property-with-getter-can-i-not-specify-an-initial-value). `init()` must be called with a context. I called it in the `onCreate()` of the MainActivity. But there was a problematic situation.

Let's say there is another activity, `Activity2`. In the MainAcvitiy, I started Activity2. Then, I pressed the home button and used other apps. Now, I came back to my application, and it crashed. I read the log. It seemed that my app had restarted, but MainAcivity was skipped and it started directly from `Activity2`. This was not something I expected. Since the singleton class was only initialized in the MainActivity, if the app starts from `Activity2`, it is not initialized.

I could put the initialization code to the `onCreate()` of all activities, but that seems to be a bad thing. I think I could subclassing `Application` and do the initialization there. But is that the right place? The documentation says there normally is no need to subclass Application.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.loser, PID: 32117
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.loser/com.loser.Activity2}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Call init() first.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3454)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3494)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Call init() first.
   at com.loser.MySingleton$Companion.getInstance(MySingleton.kt:44)
   at com.loser.Activity2.onResume(Activity2.kt:93)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1270)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6788)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3431)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3494) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: initialize your singleton inside Application class onCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would initialize it in the Application class in the `onCreate` method and then `get()` the instance everywhere.

Or You can pass the Context object itself to the `get` method to init the instance if it's not initialized yet.

```
if(_instance == null) init();
```

Comment: I tried to avoid passing a context every time I get the instance. I mean, currently it is `MySingleton.instance.doSomethng()`, but if I pass a context, it will be like `MySingleton.getInstance(this@MyFragment.context).doSomethng()`. Although by that way, I would not have to use `init()`, that would make the code look ugly.

Comment: I agree with you, but sometimes you don't want to always initialize the object with the Application class unless you need it anywhere in the app (lazy loading).

Comment: Not everywhere, but it is and will be used at least in several activities and fragments. And it is needed in the MainActivity right after the app has started. I guess I would use the `Application` way.

Comment: That would make perfect sense to me then!

Comment: @DamnVegetables are you passing activity context.? Note that activity context is tied to lifecycle of the activity.

Comment: I would also check this way of creating a Sigeltone in Kotlin. It looks clearer to me https://github.com/dbacinski/Design-Patterns-In-Kotlin#singleton

Comment: I just passed the MainActivity's this. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the `Context` you can use any context or `getApplicationContext()`. The initialization has to work this way. If not, we would need more informations (log).

Comment: I have attached the exception log. But, I cannot call `getApplicationContext()` in a class, can I?